# How to assign custom action to mouse middle click (something like libinput-gestures for mouse)?

Tags: 18.04, mouse

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 and I want to assign a cstom action to middle click of my mouse. How that can be done? for example libinput-gestures (https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) allows you to set custom actions to your trackpad gestures. Is there something like that for mouse also?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with middle mouse button? it will give you quick answers..

Comment: middle click to show all windows or middle click simulates some key press like super (windows key).

Comment: If by any chance you're using a Corsair mouse, then you can use this Linux driver: https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next

Comment: I found easystroke the most suitable for the purpose.

`sudo apt install easystoke`

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with two packages installed..

`xbindkeys` and `xdotool`

1. `sudo apt install xbindkeys`
2. `sudo apt install xdotool`

create a file name `.xbindkeysrc` in your home folder

3. `touch /home/user/.xbindkeysrc`
4. `gedit /home/user/.xbindkesyrc`
5. paste the below content

Content:

```
"xdotool sleep 0.5 key Super_L"
b:2
```

6. run `xbindkeys -p`

Please note that when you click mouse middle button which is `b:2` It will simulate key press of `Super_L` only for once.. again if you press `b:2` It don't do anything as opposed to pressing `Super_L`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ touch /home/pratap/.xbindkeysrc
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gedit .xbindkeysrc
pratap@i7-4770:~$ xbindkeys -p
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

Comment: its not perfect (indeed midclick no.2 gets lost), but is a start